# Editing System Environment Variables is allowed only when opened through Control Panel

Tags: windows, windows-10, environment-variables

On Windows 10, if I open the Environment Variables window directly through Windows Search, I can't edit the System Variables (buttons are disabled):

[image]
[image]

However, opening it through Control Panel (Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables) enables editing:

[image]

Maybe related: I recently editted some registry keys related to Users.

I'd like to be able to edit System Variables either way.

Comment: Invoke the editor directly with `rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Start Menu item is specifically titled "Edit environment variables for your account", so that's what it lets you do. I suspect the difference is that it doesn't go through UAC, while the other Control Panel link does.

Use the Start Menu item "Edit the system environment variables" instead.

[image]